# are there any downsides to add params within a custom route path for the controller method to create a polymorphic instance in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, routes

I have the following in my code:

```rb
resources :sessions do
      ...
      member do
        put :vote
      end
end
```

and within my controller:

```rb
def vote
      emoji_symbol = params[:emoji]
      vote = Vote.find_or_create_by(voteable_id: @session.id, voteable_type: 'Session', user: current_user)
      vote.send(emoji_symbol) ? vote.update(emoji_symbol.to_sym => false) : vote.update(emoji_symbol.to_sym => true)
    end
```

to make it work from my view I have to call the following now:

```rb
  = link_to vote_backend_session_path(@session.id, emoji: :air), method: :put, ...`
```

I am wondering if there are any downsides to this approach, since I am more familiar with using the `..._params`, `form_for` permitting specific required values and adding a new nested controller.

So what would be 'best practice' here and what are possible downsides to my approach?
Would one ever add params within path in rails?
Does it make a difference when I want to reuse my vote for other controllers as well?